# WCF streaming large number objects

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, streaming, chunking

I have a WCF service that query a database and returns a large number of records.  There is so many records, that the server runs out of memory and fails before it can return.

So I want to send the records back as I fetch them from the database, or a set number back at a time.

For additional clarity, I cannot collect call records fetched into a collection on the server, as the server runs out of memory before I have collected all the records.  I want to try and find away to send them back one by one or in chunks, in one call.

> For example, in chunks:
>
> 1. Fetch first 1000 records
> 2. Add to collection
> 3. Send collection to client
> 4. Clear collection
> 5. Fetch next 1000 records, and repeat from step 2

So the idea I have how the web service code will look something like this:

```
Public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
     // Setup Query
     string query = PrepareQuery();

     // Create Connection
     connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
     connection.Open();

     var sqlcommand = connection.CreateCommand();
     sqlcommand.CommandText = query.ToString();

     // Read Results
     var reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         Customer customer = new Customer();
         foreach (var column in Columns)
         {
             int fieldIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(column);
             object value = reader.GetValue(fieldIndex);
             customer[column.Name] = value;
         }

         yield return customer;
     }
}
```

I don't want to consider paging as the `Order By` on the SQL server is slow.

Looking for way to do this in WCF

Comment: WCF is nothing to do with the problem. It is system design flaw. And your question is very broad.

Comment: What type of database? If you have a SQL Server I recommend using one of their command line utilities like SQLCMD.EXE.  If is much faster than using a Net Library method.  Utilities are meant to archive the database and can handle any size database.  I have a few c# applications the creates a .BAT file with the SQLCMD and outputs results as CSV.  Then reads CSV into c#.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Comment: Hopefully I have narrowed down the problem @Reniuz, with the additional clarity.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the alternative suggestion, but we cannot use utilities like this because of the environment we wish to use in the future.

Comment: You doing something wrong. And yet it is design problems. You should first deal with other problems. You should answer first: Do client really need so much data? Why ordering is slow? Do you use indexes? Is your query good and uses indexes? ...And then I would go with chunked data solution.

Comment: @Reniuz I appreciate the different view point to my problem.  The client does need so much data in the worst the case, there is filter that is apply to reduce the data set, but I am trying to solve for the worst case here.  Ordering is slow because the table being queried was is using data stores.

Comment: If the ordering is issue not to use chunks, how would you deal with ordering when you stream data?

Comment: @Reniuz The data does not need to be ordered.  So in this case it would be fine.

Comment: I see you just want to use Streaming option and that's it. Yes it is an option, yes it is possible and yes it will be hard way if you have no experience with streaming. Of course new things to learn is very good idea. So [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2012/09/06/custom-wcf-streaming/) is the reference to start with. Good luck :)

Comment: SQLCMD.EXE is part of the standard SQL Server installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to [mikelegg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8694636/mikelegg) & [Reniuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754438/reniuz)  for helping come to a solution.  I wish I could give them the tick for the right answer, but I am a afraid the next developer to read this question would not fully benefit.  So where is what I ended up with.

1. Setup the config files for the Server and Client (Follow link: [Large Data and Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming))
2. Followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2012/09/06/custom-wcf-streaming/#comment-3305) solution, can download source code from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Custom-WCF-Streaming-436861e6)

I had to change  the DBRowStream.DBThreadProc method a bit to work so I post the source code:

DBRowStream Class:

```
    void DBThreadProc(object o)
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand com = null;

        try
        {
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(/*ConnectionString*/);
            com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = PrepareQuery();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;

            MemoryStream memStream = memStream1;
            memStreamWriteStatus = 1;
            readyToWriteToMemStream1.WaitOne();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Populate
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                foreach (var column in Columns)
                {
                    int fieldIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(column);
                    object value = reader.GetValue(fieldIndex);
                    customer[column.Name] = value;
                }                   

                // Serialize: I used a custom Serializer 
                // but BinaryFormatter should be fine
                DBDataFormatter.Serialize(memStream, customer);

                count++;

                if (count == PAGESIZE) // const int PAGESIZE = 10000
                {
                    switch (memStreamWriteStatus)
                    {
                        case 1: // done writing to stream 1
                            {
                                memStream1.Position = 0;
                                readyToSendFromMemStream1.Set();
                                // write stream 1 is done...waiting for stream 2 
                                readyToWriteToMemStream2.WaitOne();
                                memStream = memStream2;
                                memStream.Position = 0;
                                memStream.SetLength(0); // Added:To Reset the stream. Else was getting garbage data back
                                memStreamWriteStatus = 2;

                                break;
                            }
                        case 2: // done writing to stream 2
                            {
                                memStream2.Position = 0;
                                readyToSendFromMemStream2.Set();
                                // Write on stream 2 is done...waiting for stream 1
                                readyToWriteToMemStream1.WaitOne();
                                // done waiting for stream 1 
                                memStream = memStream1;
                                memStreamWriteStatus = 1;
                                memStream.Position = 0;
                                memStream.SetLength(0); // Added: Reset the stream. Else was getting garbage data back

                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                switch (memStreamWriteStatus)
                {
                    case 1: // done writing to stream 1
                        {
                            memStream1.Position = 0;
                            readyToSendFromMemStream1.Set();
                            // END write stream 1 is done...waiting for stream 2 
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2: // done writing to stream 2
                        {
                            memStream2.Position = 0;
                            readyToSendFromMemStream2.Set();
                            // END write stream 2 is done...waiting for stream 1 
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            bDoneWriting = true;
            bCanRead = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (com != null)
            {
                com.Dispose();
                com = null;
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                con = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then the Client side:

```
private static void TestGetRecordsAndDump()
{
    const string FILE_NAME = "Records.CSV";
    File.Delete(FILE_NAME);
    var file = File.AppendText(FILE_NAME);
    long count = 0;
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.DataServiceClient();
        var stream = service.GetDBRowStream();

        Console.WriteLine("Records Retrieved : ");
        Console.WriteLine("File Size (MB)    : ");

        var canDoLastRead = true;
        while (stream.CanRead && canDoLastRead)
        {
           try
           {
               Customer customer = DBDataFormatter.Deserialize(stream); // Used custom Deserializer, but BinaryFormatter should be fine

               file.Write(customer.ToString());

               count++;
           }
           catch
           {
                canDoLastRead = false; // Bug: stream.CanRead is not set to false at the end of stream, so I do this trick to know if I finished retruning all records.
           }
           finally
           {
               Console.SetCursorPosition("Records Retrieved : ".Length, 0);
               Console.Write(string.Format("{0}               ", count));
               Console.SetCursorPosition("File Size (MB)    : ".Length, 1);
               Console.Write(string.Format("{0:G}             ", file.BaseStream.Length / 1024f / 1024f));     
           }
        }
        finally
        {
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a bug I cannot seem to solve, that `stream.CanRead` is not set to false, then all the records have been returned, have not been able to work out why, but at least now, I can query large data sets, and return all records, with out the server or client running out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

I think you answer your own question. There are 2 ways to do it, stream or chunk.

You can do streaming in wcf - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming

You get a Stream to write to, so you need to handle yourself how you are going to encode your data on that stream, and how you are going decode it at the client.

The alternative is you do chunking/paging. You just modify your service so it accepts e.g. a page number or some other way to indicate which page is needed.

Which one you do depends on the application, eg how much data? what is the nature of the client? is it possible to use some field to page on? etc etc

Here is some psudo code for making a stream that can do this on the server side. It is based on the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming

I'm not writing the full compilable code for you, but this is the gist of it.

In the server:

```
public Stream GetBigData()
{
    return new BigDataStream();
}
```

BigDataStream (the non-implimented methods are not shown):

```
class BigDataStream : Stream
{
    public BigDataStream()
    {
        // open DB connection
        // run your query
        // get a DataReader
    }

    // you need a buffer to encode your data between calls to Read
    List<byte> _encodeBuffer = new List<byte>();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // read from the DataReader and populate the _encodeBuffer
        // until the _encodeBuffer contains at least count bytes
        // (or until there are no more records)
        // for example:

        while (_encodeBuffer.Count < count && _reader.Read())
        {
            // (1)
            // encode the record into a byte array. How to do this?
            // you can read into a class and then use the data 
            // contract serialization for example. If you do this, you
            // will probably find it easier to prepend an integer which
            // specifies the length of the following encoded message. 
            // This will make it easier for the client to deserialize it.

            // (2)
            // append the encoded record bytes (plus any length prefix 
            // etc) to _encodeBuffer
        }

        // remove up to the first count bytes from _encodeBuffer
        // and copy them into buffer at the offset requested

        // return the number of bytes added
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        // close the reader + db connection
        base.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: So from what I understand, is that with streaming, you have to fetch all records into a collection then write them to the stream (on the server side).  Problem I am facing is that that I get a out of memory exception before I finish collecting all the records.  Paging is an option, but then I need to 'order by' on the SQL server, which is slow

Comment: You do not nead to fetch all the records into memory for streaming. Run your query to get e.g. a DataReader. Then have a loop which (1) reads a record (2) encodes the record (3) writes the encoded record to the stream

Comment: Actually, you are right, I have not fully thought this through. I think with streaming you can do it without loading all data up front, but it will be fiddly. You need to return a Stream from your server method, which WCF will then read from for you. So I think you would need to make a custom stream that will make your query then iterate the result and output it as bytes.

Comment: Thanks mikelegg most useful information I have gotten so far.  The question I have is how?  Is there some example code somewhere, am kinda new to streams.